# Is there an algorithm for finding amount of sublists whose sum is smaller than given K? Better than O(N^2)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

Example:

```
Sublists where sum is smaller than given K (K is the maximum sum).
[-1, 1, -2, 1, -1,]
N = -1

[-1, 1, -2]
[-2]
[-2, 1, -1]
[-1, 1, -2, 1, -1]
```

There is 4 of them.

I have found algorithms for this but they only covered non-negative numbers.

Thanks.

(Example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-subarrays-sum-less-k/ this is what I need but the algorithm there doesn't work with negative numbers)

Comment: I thought of that but I need an algorithm better than O(n^2) at least O(n logn) Should probably put that in the question

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: I have a list with numbers (e.g. [1, 2, 1, 3] and I need to find amount of sublists that have a sum smaller than N. If N was 4 than the lists would be
[1], [1, 2], [2, 1] etc. [2, 1, 3] woudln't qualify because 2 + 1 + 3 is 6

Comment: I don't think there is one. The efficiency is achieved through the knowledge that the sum can only increment, so as soon as you hit the L limit you can stop searching. But if that possibility vanishes because you have a negative number, then this optimization cannot be used. Imagine if the last number was something like -(MAX(ABS(list_n-1))+L)*len(list). Then all sublists would be valid because the last element would trump any sum of its predecessors. And you know this only when you examine all elements for all sublists -- which is O(N^2).

Comment: I had similiar thoughts, I would give you correct answer if this wasn't a comment.

Comment: The *size* of the output isn't O(n^2); there's no way you can even iterate over it in O(n^2) time, let alone *generate* it. Note that the length of the list `n` is entirely distinct from the bound `N`.

Comment: @chepner, the question only asks for sublists - i.e. contiguous subsequences - not all subsets. There are quadratically many sublists. The output is a single integer.

Comment: "Sublist" isn't a terribly well defined term, but yes, that does make a difference.

Comment: N is the maximum sum, will edit to make it clearer

Comment: Idea to explore: calculate the sums of the first k for all k .≤ n Sort the array by these sums via merge sort, counting  inversions as we go (and associating original indices with sums). Valid answers are inversions and noninverted pairs of indices that satisfy our difference is less than n. TBD how do we avoid double counting inverted pairs that satisfy difference less yhan n?

Comment: I think that `[-1, -1], [-2, -1]` are also such subsets

Comment: @Geeocode as someone noted, I meant contiguous subsequences. I didn't know the correct terminology

Comment: The title reads smaller than given N. This must be a typo.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It was, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the original array be *A*, and make an array S of cumulative sums, so that *S[i] = Sum of the first i elements of A*.  Note that *S* will be one element longer than *A*.

Now, for each sublist of A from A[i] to A[j], the sum of its elements is S[j+1]-S[i]

To get your answer, all we need to do is count the number of pairs of indexes (i,j) in S with i < j and S[j]-S[i] < K.

You can do this with an order statistic tree: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree

This is a binary search tree augmented with records of each subtree's size, which lets you answer questions like "how many entries have values <= x" in O(log N) time.

Start with the tree empty, then:

```
for j=1 to S.length-1:
    add S[j-1] to the tree
    query for the number of elements in the tree with values > S[j] - K
    add that count to the total
```

Total complexity is O(N log N) (where N is the size of the input!), dominated by the O(log N) add and query operations in the tree for each *j*.

Comment: I think it should be `> S[j] - N`

Comment: Also it seems unwise to use `N` as an additional input as in the question and as the size of the input for the runtime considerations.

Comment: @yassin  Thanks. Corrected.  w.r.t. N, yeah, but you know what I mean, and I think the OP did the same thing.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, I will try and mark this as an answer if I confirm it. I will also edit my question to change N to K, because it could be confusing

Answer (score -2):

If your lists contain negative numbers, it is impossible to know anything about their sums without summing every member.

Comment: What exactly is "summing every member", and why would that imply complexity > O(N)?